# Get Mongo Collection in Meteor velocity test

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

Currently I'm working on a meteor project, in which I wrote some packages. Now I have a problem when writing test codes for these packages.
   I used mike:mocha in Velocity.

In package I've created a Collection using:

```
    TestCollect = new Meteor.Collection("testCollect");
```

and in my package/server.js

```
    if(TestCollect.find().count == 0){
        TestCollect.insert({});
    }
    ... ／＊I want to make sure there is only doc in this collection */
```

Then I export this variable in package.js

```
    api.export("TestCollect");
```

and in my server test code, it's like:

```
    it("should contain only one doc", function(){
            console.log(TestCollect.find());
            chai.assert.equal(1, TestCollect.find().count(), "but it has " + TestCollect.find().count() + " docs");
        });
```

To my surprise, seems the db in the test code is totally different from the db in my packages. I guess velocity use a mirror mongo to run test codes.

In fact, the console.log(TestCollect.find()); in my test code returns:

```
    I20150102-08:44:13.285(8)? [velocity-mirror] { _mongo: 
    I20150102-08:44:13.285(8)?    { _connectCallbacks: [ [Function] ],
    I20150102-08:44:13.285(8)?      _observeMultiplexers: {},
    I20150102-08:44:13.285(8)?      _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 0, callbacks: {}                         },
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?      _docFetcher: { _mongoConnection: [Circular],         _callbacksForCacheKey: {} },
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?      _oplogHandle: 
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?       { _oplogUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/local',
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?         _dbName: 'mocha',
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?         _oplogLastEntryConnection: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?         _oplogTailConnection: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?         _stopped: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.286(8)?         _tailHandle: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?         _readyFuture: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?         _crossbar: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?         _lastProcessedTS: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?         _baseOplogSelector: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?         _catchingUpFutures: [] },
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?      db: 
    I20150102-08:44:13.287(8)?       { domain: null,
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         _events: {},
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         _maxListeners: 10,
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         databaseName: 'mocha',
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         serverConfig: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         options: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         _applicationClosed: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.288(8)?         slaveOk: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         bufferMaxEntries: -1,
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         native_parser: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         bsonLib: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         bson: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         bson_deserializer: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         bson_serializer: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.289(8)?         _state: 'connected',
    I20150102-08:44:13.290(8)?         pkFactory: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.290(8)?         forceServerObjectId: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.290(8)?         safe: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.290(8)?         notReplied: {},
    I20150102-08:44:13.291(8)?         isInitializing: true,
    I20150102-08:44:13.291(8)?         openCalled: true,
    I20150102-08:44:13.291(8)?         commands: [],
    I20150102-08:44:13.291(8)?         logger: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.291(8)?         tag: 1420159452700,
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         eventHandlers: [Object],
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         serializeFunctions: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         raw: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         recordQueryStats: false,
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
    I20150102-08:44:13.292(8)?         numberOfRetries: 60,
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?         readPreference: [Object] },
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?      _primary: '127.0.0.1:3001' },
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?   _cursorDescription: 
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?    { collectionName: 'kliuStatus',
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?      selector: {},
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?      options: { transform: null } },
    I20150102-08:44:13.293(8)?   _synchronousCursor: null }
```

Then how should I get this test code to work? Any way to connect to the "real" mongo？

Comment: What are you testing? It looks like you're testing whether Meteor's MongoDB API works. [Don't unit test other people's code.](http://blog.markrendle.net/dont-unit-test-trivial-code/)

Comment: @sbking , hi, the code I pasted is just a demo. I need to test the data written into Mongo collection from my package is really what I want to be written into. So I insert data by using my package, and then I want to check whether it really goes to mongo. But currently I can't get the correct mongo db in my test code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that tests run inside the mirror and do so on a different database.

What you should do in each test is setup the database you need for that test. So when you're writing a test you should perform some steps that are similar to this (untested code):

```
describe('the suite'), function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
       myCollection.remove({});
    });

    it('should add something to some document', function() {
        // SETUP
        myCollection.insert({some: "document"});

        // EXECUTE
        myCode.addSomething({hello: "world"});

        // VERIFY
        myDoc = myCollection.find({some: "document"});
        assert(myDoc.hello === "world");
    }

});
```

You can see more about hooks in mocha [here](http://mochajs.org/#hooks)

https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/blob/master/specs/example.js

Comment: Thank you, and could you please give me more instructions how to do it?Currently I've decleared a collection in js that shared by client&server, and js only loaded by server would do some data work. All this would be automatically done after I add this package in my meteor project. So how could I “add" the package to my test project and make all the data work happened in my test project?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the "test project" is. The packages you have in your app are the same ones you get in the mirror. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The package I wrote will automatically create a collection and add some data into it. So I think when my mocha test code runs it would do the same in the "mirror" mongo database. And I wrote test code to check this to ensure my package is working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and fixed in when I realized that I wasn't using Meteor.subscribe. I suspect if you add the following code to your client: `Meteor.subscribe("TestCollect")` mike:mocha will work correctly.