# Suddenly seeing lots of Mongo output in server console (Mongo Oplog?)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I absolutely can't think what to Google for this one. It happens when I start meteor up from the command line.

I get a load of output that I don't recognise, and it's a bit annoying because it obscures the output that I want to see. I can't pinpoint the change that made this happen.

I thought I'd observed it happening after DB queries were made too, however I can't see that this morning.

```
I20150707-10:26:06.097(1)? ----------------------------
I20150707-10:26:06.101(1)? { _mongo: 
I20150707-10:26:06.101(1)?    { _observeMultiplexers: 
I20150707-10:26:06.101(1)?       { '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"bhJwk7Lc4mPDzAYno"},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"profile":1,"username":1,"emails":1}}}': [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"bhJwk7Lc4mPDzAYno","services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken":"+uhnI7co8s08w/9A53RTBO+qH/jJvKnHJCIYwRIKZ64="},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"_id":1}}}': [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"bhJwk7Lc4mPDzAYno"},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"roles":1}}}': [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration","selector":{},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"secret":0}}}': [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"projects","selector":{"user_ids":"bhJwk7Lc4mPDzAYno"},"options":{"transform":null}}': [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"sourceTypes","selector":{},"options":{"transform":null}}': [Object] },
I20150707-10:26:06.102(1)?      _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 7, callbacks: [Object] },
I20150707-10:26:06.103(1)?      db: 
I20150707-10:26:06.103(1)?       { domain: null,
I20150707-10:26:06.103(1)?         _events: {},
I20150707-10:26:06.103(1)?         _maxListeners: 10,
I20150707-10:26:06.103(1)?         databaseName: 'meteor',
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         serverConfig: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         options: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         _applicationClosed: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         slaveOk: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         bufferMaxEntries: -1,
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         native_parser: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.104(1)?         bsonLib: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.105(1)?         bson: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.105(1)?         bson_deserializer: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.105(1)?         bson_serializer: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.105(1)?         _state: 'connected',
I20150707-10:26:06.106(1)?         pkFactory: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.106(1)?         forceServerObjectId: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         safe: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         notReplied: {},
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         isInitializing: true,
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         openCalled: true,
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         commands: [],
I20150707-10:26:06.107(1)?         logger: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.108(1)?         tag: 1436261154640,
I20150707-10:26:06.108(1)?         eventHandlers: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.108(1)?         serializeFunctions: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.108(1)?         raw: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.109(1)?         recordQueryStats: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.109(1)?         retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
I20150707-10:26:06.109(1)?         numberOfRetries: 60,
I20150707-10:26:06.109(1)?         readPreference: [Object] },
I20150707-10:26:06.110(1)?      _primary: '127.0.0.1:3001',
I20150707-10:26:06.110(1)?      _oplogHandle: 
I20150707-10:26:06.110(1)?       { _oplogUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/local',
I20150707-10:26:06.110(1)?         _dbName: 'meteor',
I20150707-10:26:06.111(1)?         _oplogLastEntryConnection: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.111(1)?         _oplogTailConnection: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.111(1)?         _stopped: false,
I20150707-10:26:06.111(1)?         _tailHandle: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.112(1)?         _readyFuture: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.112(1)?         _crossbar: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.112(1)?         _baseOplogSelector: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.113(1)?         _catchingUpFutures: [],
I20150707-10:26:06.113(1)?         _lastProcessedTS: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.114(1)?         _onSkippedEntriesHook: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.114(1)?         _entryQueue: [Object],
I20150707-10:26:06.115(1)?         _workerActive: false },
I20150707-10:26:06.115(1)?      _docFetcher: { _mongoConnection: [Circular], _callbacksForCacheKey: {} } },
I20150707-10:26:06.116(1)?   _cursorDescription: 
I20150707-10:26:06.116(1)?    { collectionName: 'scrapeLog',
I20150707-10:26:06.116(1)?      selector: {},
I20150707-10:26:06.116(1)?      options: { transform: null, sort: [Object], limit: 10 } },
I20150707-10:26:06.116(1)?   _synchronousCursor: null }
```

Comment: Have you searched your entire project for `console.log` to see where this could be coming from? It may be a package though, so it might be helpful to post the output of running `meteor list` in the terminal (in the root directory of your project).

Comment: I have just had a look for console, but nothing obvious. Does anyone recognise what this output is? It doesn't seem like an error.

I've removed the two packages I've added recently and does still persist.

Comment: The question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736268/get-mongo-collection-in-meteor-velocity-test would imply it's the result of doing `console.log(SomeCollection.find());`. Perhaps something similar in yours or a package's code? You may have meant `console.log(SomeCollection.find().fetch());`

Comment: This is the answer. In the end on searching on the string '----------------------------' was the unique signature.

Would love to get a line number with the console.log....